# Is there any setting in eclipse adt to not create appcompactv_n each time

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

In my ADT whenever I create a new application it creates new  appcompactv_n can I stop it or it will happen like this .please make me is there any way..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's included because your minimum SDK version is set to `10`. The `ActionBar` was introduced in `API 11`. `Eclipse` adds it automatically so your app can look more consistent throughout the spectrum of all **android versions** you are supporting.

And to exclude  try this:

create a new android project, uncheck Create Activity in step-2 (Config project).

Or try this

1. Choose Project Properties
2. Android
3. at Library box just remove appcompat_vn_x and add appcompat_vn.
4. Now you can delete appcompat_vn_x.

Note : in **appcompat_vn**, **n** is number of library for e.g. **appcompat_v7**

Comment: @JogendraGouda Happy to help,If this answer helped you,then please mark it as accepted,so it may help others also.Enjoy coding.